# What's the meaning of this service specification

Tags: formal-methods

What's the meaning of the example statement here?

"A service specification S describes an interface: it specifies the behavior of certain program elements (functions or subprograms) through statements expressed in program logic. For instance, these might be such statements:

1. [...]
2. *x, y : N[{x>0} y := x * x {y > x}]*

"

The quote is from the article  "On The Hourglass Model"
By Micah Beck,
Communications of the ACM, July 2019, Vol. 62 No. 7, Pages 48-57

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means:

  For all natural numbers x and y,
    if the value of variable x is greater than zero
    then after the assignment statement "y := x*x" is executed
    the predicate "y > x" will be true.